# I do not understand the following construction using -tte iu nara

Tags: grammar, translation

[image: goku says ~ni modoru tte iunara]

Goku (the character speaking) says “~ni modorutte iunara” here, and I’m not sure what it means.

I can only guess the “iu” means “say” and the “nara” is used to state an authorative truth, but that only makes half sense.

Translations of this are not literal enough (“if you agree to go back to …”) to understand the grammatical nuances here.

What does it really decompose to?

Comment: Where did you get that なら is "used to state an authorative truth."?

Comment: `“nara” is used to state an authorative truth` -- I'm sorry but I don't understand. Have you looked up なら in a dictionary? eg https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89

Comment: It’s in Makino: nara behind the verb/noun states something as true according to the speaker.

Comment: What is Makino? Googling doesn't really seem to bring up anything relevant.

Comment: Even your link says so “that being the case”. 
Even with your link my question remains the same.

Comment: Makino is colloquial for by far the most widely used book on Japanese grammar…

Comment: It's a conditional. You can think of it as "if" loosely. Quite different from a statement of authoritative truth.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar. Thank you. Never heard anyone refer to it by the author's name.

Comment: Actually it is not only used conditionally but also used authoratively as in “I’m saying this is true, so in that case” - your link prettty much says the same. I’m assuming that’s what happens here but am confused about the iu and general construction.

Comment: I'm not the same person as Chocolate, but okay. Anyway, it seemed like you were unaware of the conditional meaning, which is the primary usage. Yes... that one translation you're mentioning is in definition #3 on the Jisho page as well. I would still consider that conditional.

Comment: Probably my description of authorative is unclear and inaccurate although it seems nara can be used to push the statement rather than keeping it a condition. Then it seems the crux is in the “iu”, which I don’t understand like I said

Comment: Or is it just “(if you) say you will.. then)”?

Comment: #3は品詞が違います。#3 is a different part of speech. なら as #3 is 接続詞. It's a shortened form of それなら "If that's the case". You use it this way:「なら、助けてやる。」=「それなら、助けてやる。」"If that's the case, I will help you." The なら in your question is a 助詞 meaning "if", not a 接続詞.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now from the comments, I was getting hung up on a complex meaning of nara - that may not exist.

The iu just stands for “say”, so “if you say you will return to .., then, …”

Silly, I know